# How to Center-align the POS Order Receipt in Odoo POS Module?

Tags: odoo, point-of-sale, receipt

In the POS order receipt generated by the Odoo POS module, the receipt is currently aligned to the left. I would like to know how to centre-align this. Odoo developers, could you please provide an answer to this question? Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXP0o.jpg)

I would like to know how to centre-align this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.